# Why aren't my fixtures being inserted into my Mongo collection in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Only 5 of my fixtures are being displayed in my Chrome console when I run `Files.find().fetch()`. As you can see, I have many more fixtures that I'd like to add to my collection. The first file is in /lib, and is called `files.js`, and looks like this:

```
Files = new Mongo.Collection('files');

Meteor.methods({
    deleteFile: function(id) {
        // check to see if user is actually the owner of the file
        var file = Files.findOne(id);
        if (Meteor.userId() != file.owner) {
            // user could've sent any data, but we want the one in the database,
            //   so we find do Files.findOne(id).owner instead of data.owner
            throw new Meteor.Error('Not Authorized', 'User is not the right owner?');
        }

        Files.remove({_id: id});
    },
    insertFile: function(data) {
        // user must be logged in
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('Not Authorized', 'User is not logged in!');
        }

        // set owner
        data.owner = Meteor.userId();

        // insert into the db collection
        Files.insert(data);
    },
    updateFile: function(id, data) {
        // user must be logged in
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('Not Authorized', 'User is not logged in!');
        }

        // check to see if user is actually the owner of the file
        var file = Files.findOne(id);
        if (Meteor.userId() != file.owner) {
            // user could've sent any data, but we want the one in the database,
            //   so we find do Files.findOne(id).owner instead of data.owner
            throw new Meteor.Error('Not Authorized', 'User is not the right owner?');
        }
        // ensure data belongs to current user, client can't change the user
        data.owner = Meteor.userId();
        // update the db collection
        Files.update(id, data);
    }
});
```

The second file is in /server, and is called `fixtures.js`, and looks like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
// code to run on server at startup
// count recipes entry
var num = Files.find().count();
if (num === 0) {
    var fixtures = [
        {
            username: 'FakeUser-1',
            firstName: 'John1',
            lastName: 'Smith',
            email: 'k@opt.net',
            phone: '555-555-5555',
            streetAdd: '8 Milk Street',
            town: 'Compton',
            state: 'NY',
            econtact: {
                eName: 'Jane Smith',
                phone: '555-555-5555'
            },
            prefs: 'deaf',
            admin: false
        },
        {
            username: 'FakeUser-2',
            firstName: 'John2',
            lastName: 'Smith',
            email: 'k@opt.net',
            phone: '555-555-5555',
            streetAdd: '8 Milk Street',
            town: 'Compton',
            state: 'NY',
            econtact: {
                eName: 'Jane Smith',
                phone: '555-555-5555'
            },
            prefs: 'deaf',
            admin: false
        },
        {
            username: 'FakeUser-3',
            firstName: 'John3',
            lastName: 'Smith',
            email: 'k@opt.net',
            phone: '555-555-5555',
            streetAdd: '8 Milk Street',
            town: 'Compton',
            state: 'NY',
            econtact: {
                eName: 'Jane Smith',
                phone: '555-555-5555'
            },
            prefs: 'deaf',
            admin: false
        },
        {
            username: 'FakeUser-4',
            firstName: 'John4',
            lastName: 'Smith',
            email: 'k@opt.net',
            phone: '555-555-5555',
            streetAdd: '8 Milk Street',
            town: 'Compton',
            state: 'NY',
            econtact: {
                eName: 'Jane Smith',
                phone: '555-555-5555'
            },
            prefs: 'deaf',
            admin: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-1',
            fileName: 'my_FakeFileAA.py',
            ancestor: 'master-fakeFileA.py',
            content: '',
            type: 'python',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-1',
            fileName: 'FakeFileAB.py',
            ancestor: 'master-fakeFileA.py',
            content: '',
            type: 'python',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-1',
            fileName: 'myFakeFileBA.py',
            ancestor: 'master-fakeFileB.py',
            content: '',
            type: 'python',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-1',
            fileName: 'myFakeFileBB.py',
            ancestor: 'master-fakeFileB.py',
            content: '',
            type: 'python',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-1',
            fileName: 'default-1A.web',
            ancestor: 'default.web',
            content: ['', '', ''],
            type: 'web',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-1',
            fileName: 'default-1B.web',
            ancestor: 'default.web',
            content: ['', '', ''],
            type: 'web',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-2',
            fileName: 'default-2A.web',
            ancestor: 'default.web',
            content: ['', '', ''],
            type: 'web',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-3',
            fileName: 'default-3A.web',
            ancestor: 'default.web',
            content: ['', '', ''],
            type: 'web',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-3',
            fileName: 'default-3B.web',
            ancestor: 'default.web',
            content: ['', '', ''],
            type: 'web',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-3',
            fileName: 'default-3C.web',
            ancestor: 'default.web',
            content: ['', '', ''],
            type: 'web',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-3',
            fileName: 'default-3D.web',
            ancestor: 'default.web',
            content: ['', '', ''],
            type: 'web',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-3',
            fileName: 'default-3E.web',
            ancestor: 'default.web',
            content: ['', '', ''],
            type: 'web',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: true
        },
        {
            owner: 'FakeUser-4',
            fileName: 'default.web',
            ancestor: 'default.web',
            content: ['', '', ''],
            type: 'web',
            creationDate: new Date(),
            modifiedDate: new Date(),
            private: false
        }
    ];

    fixtures.forEach(function(element) {
        Files.insert(element);
    });
}
});
```

In particular, the only 5 documents that are being inserted are the first 4 listed above and the very last one (perhaps this helps). I'm using Meteor.js version 1.5.1.

AMENDMENT:
Also, when I open `meteor mongo` > `use files` > `db.files.find().count()` I get 0. I'm really at a loss here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you mix 2 different document types into the same collection?

Comment: From just looking at it, I have a suspicion your code works but your observation is wrong. How do you count the number of documents inserted?

Comment: @Styx I'm aware, will separate them out later

Comment: @dnickless I use `Files.find().count()` in the code above and I use `Files.find().fetch()` in my Chrome console and just look at the 5 Objects that are there. (I tried reseting and restarting Meteor too, by the way)

Comment: I would try adding some debug output in the fixtures.forEach call just to see if you insert statement actually gets called n times. Have you tried emptying your collection and starting all over? Are you looking at the right db/collection? Stupid questions to ask but this seems a little obscure...

Comment: Unrelated note, you need to `check(id, String)` to prevent injection (e.g. `Meteor.call("deleteFile", {$exists: true})` where the first file happens to belong to you)

Comment: If you do not reset your DB between startups, your `if (num ===0)` condition will prevent your bootstrap fixtures from being executed.

Comment: Your code works fine, it inserts 17 documents inside the "files" collection. But you are using the wrong mongo commands. You must not use `use files`. Just use : `meteor mongo` > `db.files.count()`
Clear the collection "files" by using `db.files.remove({})` and execute your code again.

Comment: @user3374348 thank you so much! @ghybs yes, I've been running `meteor reset` plenty of times. @Gaëtan Rouziès you're right, I see them in `meteor mongo` when I do it your way, but I still don't see it in my Chrome console. I did run `meteor remove insecure`, maybe that's related...?

Comment: If they are in your db, but you don't see them in your console then you are not publishing / subscribing for the data set you need.

Comment: @DavidWeldon yep, that was the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your publication, whose code I do not see, is wrong. You're probably using `Meteor.publish('files', function() {return Files.find({private: { $ne:true}});})`, which is clearly only going to return the 5 non-private files.

If you query count on the client, it will only show you what the client sees.